# Remove textarea border on button click and select next textarea automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't have idea how to do this, although I've seen it on numerouse websites. So, it is obviously an easy code, but I got stuck.

I create a simple app that displays `textarea` and a button. When you click the button, it adds one more textarea below. Therefore, I want to remove the frame (border) of the previous `textarea` when you click the add button. And also, to automatically select the next one for typing.

**CLARIFICATION**: User types in textarea some text, and presses the red button. It becomes green. And the border of the first textarea disapears (only text remains) and the added textarea below is automatically selected (clicked) and user can type in the text and again press the red button and so on. If user decide to return and change the text of previous textarea, the border will appear again.

[THERE IS THE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4PQhz/)

And here is the code:

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="30" ></textarea><br/>
<input type="button" style="background-color:red;width:48x;height:20px;" id="btn1" value="ADD" onClick="change(this);addmore();">
<div id="inner"></div><br/>

function change(myinput) { 
   myinput.style.backgroundColor = "green";
} 
function addmore() {
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.rows = 3;
        textarea.cols = 30;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = textarea.outerHTML + '<br/><input type="button" style="background-color:red;width:48px;height:20px;" id="btn2" value="ADD" onClick="change(this);addmore();"><br/>';
        document.getElementById("inner").appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: You might want to rewrite your code since 1. You should be appending the `textarea` instead of concatenating `outerHTML` so that you can reference the `textarea` 2. Inline event should not be used.

Comment: This is how you can do it in a better way: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/G4TCK/

Comment: Thank you for advice. But it doesn't solve any of the problems from the question. Can you provide fiddle where border disappears as I described and the next textarea is ready for use automatically.

Comment: If you look closely in my demo, the next `textarea` is selected automatically. About removing the border or whatever extra style you want to apply, just edit the CSS in the demo. (I have done that for you: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/G4TCK/)

Comment: About the `If user decide to return and change the text of previous textarea, the border will appear again.` statement you have, I'm not quite sure how this works. Do the `textareas` below be removed after clicking `ADD`, or...?

Comment: No not removed. The textarea border will be visible only on the textareas which are in focus (typing). When user adds textarea below and start typing there, the border from the first one is gone. But if he clicks again there, the border is visible. So complicated :(

Comment: I think you're referring to contenteditable divs, not actual textareas.

Comment: Being a beginner, I didn't heard of that type of divs. How can I apply this to my code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: DEREK. You helped me a lot with the code provided. If you put border:0 into the textarea css. It is solved. I just wonder, if this can be done with my code also, not including targets, etc...

Comment: @user3244442 - You want the border of the `textarea` to be invisible when it's not focusing too? http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/G4TCK/3/ Also, `contentEditable` is a (kind of) new attribute in HTML5. When you add that onto an element, it would be converted into an editable space. Trying adding it to this page's `body` :)

Comment: @user3244442 - If you are still thinking of adding the things you want to do to your code, I wouldn't suggest you to. You *can* add it to your code but it will be messy. Never manipulate HTML directly (except for certain cases). Modify the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) instead.